# pgfkeys: firing .unknown handler for a "parent" key

Tags: pgfkeys

Using `pgfkeys`, I automatically build some subkeys when an unknown key is encountered. See MWE below.

I would like to avoid having to set the `test` key (which is what fires the `.unknown` handler) before accessing the subkeys, ie. make it implicit. Is this possible?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\buildkeys[1]{%
    \pgfkeys{%
        /mypath/#1/a/.initial=N/A,
        /mypath/#1/b/.initial=N/A,
    }
}

\pgfkeys{%
    /mypath/.unknown/.code={%
        \expandafter\buildkeys\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
    }
}

\pgfkeys{%
    /mypath/.cd,
    test, % Needed to fire the .unknown handler. I would like to avoid this
    test/a=test a,
    test/b=test b,
}

\begin{document}

should be "test a": \pgfkeysvalueof{/mypath/test/a}

should be "test b": \pgfkeysvalueof{/mypath/test/b}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No suggestions?

Comment: Not possible. If you access `test/a` there is no check whether `test` exists first.  That is deliberate, because for many keys in PGF the parent key doesn't exist and it would be really wasteful (or even harmful) to fire `.unknown` in all of these situations.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, then it might be cleaner to do it with a `\mykeys[2]` macro that builds the keys under `#1`, then sets them from `#2`.

Comment: @HenriMenke btw is the use of `.initial` here correct? I would prefer to have them "undefined" if nothing is set by the user

Comment: If you want to leave them “undefined”, then just don't set anything.  In that case `\pgfkeysvalueof` will expand to an empty value.

Comment: Right, but if I don't set `.initial` (or `.store in` etc), the key will not be available for setting (errors out with "I do not know the key"). Just wondering the proper way of making a key available but not giving it an initial value.

Comment: `\pgfkeys{a/.initial=}` (or `\pgfkeys{a/.initial={}}` if you wish) should define it to be empty.

Comment: This doesn't work with for example etoolbox's `\ifblank` but I will post another question soon, instead of continuing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @HenriMenke that is not possible, so I may instead use this solution (but I'm still open to better ways!)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand\mykeys[2]{%
    \pgfkeys{%
        /mypath/#1/.cd,
        a/.initial=N/A,
        b/.initial=N/A,
        #2,
    }%
}

\mykeys{test}{%
    a=test a,
    b=test b,
}

\begin{document}

should be "test a": \pgfkeysvalueof{/mypath/test/a}

should be "test b": \pgfkeysvalueof{/mypath/test/b}

\end{document}
```